Auto Update Not Working On Filament Table Widget
I'm using a service that makes an API call to return data for me. I would like this data to be updated every 60 seconds. I'm aware that by default, widgets update every 10 seconds, however, my data doesn't seem to ever update after it's initial load.
I currently have this within my TopPages widget:
public function table(Tables\Table $table): Tables\Table
    {
        return $table
            ->query(TopPage::query())
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('page')
                    ->label('Page')
                    ->getStateUsing(fn ($record) => $record['page']),
                TextColumn::make('visitors')
                    ->label('Visitors')
                    ->getStateUsing(fn ($record) => number_format($record['visitors'])),
                TextColumn::make('pageviews')
                    ->label('Page Views')
                    ->getStateUsing(fn ($record) => number_format($record['pageviews'])),
            ]);
    }

and this within my TopPage model:
use Sushi;

    protected $rows;

    public function getRows(): array
    {
        $plausibleAnalyticsService = new PlausibleAnalyticsService();

        $topPages = $plausibleAnalyticsService->fetchTopPages();

        Log::info('TopPage model getRows method called');

        return $topPages;
    }

How can I have my data update every 60 seconds? I've tried adding the following, but it doesn't seem to make the api call ever again:
->poll('60s');

